# Service Connection via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, auth0

I am newbiee on pyhton development and trying to make the following example work.

The following code is for service authentication. Whenever I call `localhost:3000/callback` through browser, I am receiving `code` error because it is null.

When I create a webpage on [auth0](https://manage.auth0.com/#/), then it puts all required information and then make the source code available to use. However, code is not included. I wonder what needs to inserted.

```
token = get_token.authorization_code(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
                                         AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, code, 
                                         AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL)
```

> auth0.v3.exceptions.Auth0Error: invalid_request: Missing required
>   parameter: code

**.env**

```
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxx
AUTH0_DOMAIN=xxxxxx.auth0.com
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=v-xxxxx2yVHntpn01RoEMMxhj6RLxxxxxxxxxx
AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:3000/callback
API_IDENTIFIER={API_AUDIENCE}
```

**server.py**

```
"""Python Flask WebApp Auth0 integration example"""
from functools import wraps
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from os import environ as env, path
import json

from auth0.v3.authentication import GetToken
from auth0.v3.authentication import Users
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
from flask import redirect
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import send_from_directory
from flask import session

import constants

load_dotenv(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), ".env"))
AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL = env[constants.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL]
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID = env[constants.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID]
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET = env[constants.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET]
AUTH0_DOMAIN = env[constants.AUTH0_DOMAIN]

@APP.route('/callback')
def callback_handling():
    code = request.args.get(constants.CODE_KEY)
    get_token = GetToken(AUTH0_DOMAIN)
    auth0_users = Users(AUTH0_DOMAIN)
    #Receive exception
    token = get_token.authorization_code(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
                                         AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, code, AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL)
    user_info = auth0_users.userinfo(token['access_token'])
    session[constants.PROFILE_KEY] = json.loads(user_info)
    return redirect('/dashboard')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=env.get('PORT', 3000))
```

Comment: What do you get if you print `constants.CODE_KEY`?

Comment: @DavidCullen It prints `None`

Comment: That means you are passing `None` to `request.args.get`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: That is the issue that I reported in the question. What should I pass?

Comment: No, the issue you reported is that `code` is `None`. The real question is where is `code` supposed to come from?

Comment: I meant what is `code`, what should I put or where should I retrieve this information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150855/discussion-between-david-cullen-and-hotspring).